# Out-file stays empty

Tags: powershell

I have a txt list containing all the servers. What I want is the following:

Every server in this list needs to be pinged. The result needs to be saved in a file.

The issue, however, is that i keep getting error messages / empty output file.

```
$ServerListFile = "c:\temp\ServerList.txt"    
$ServerList = Get-Content $ServerListFile 
$output = foreach ($s in $ServerList) {
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $s -count 1 -Quiet ) {
    "$S is alive"
  }
  else {
    "$S is not responding"
  }
}
Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\ServerStatus.txt"
```

This code gives the error:

> ```
> Test-Connection : Cannot validate argument on parameter
> 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument
> that is not null or empty, and then try the co mmand again. At line:5
> char:37
> +   if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $s -count 1 -Quiet ) { "$S is ali ...
> +                                     ~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Connection], ParameterBindingValidationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
> ```

Twice.
From what I understand, the variable `$s` is empty.

However, this one should be filled with the lines of `c:\temp\ServerList.txt`

Please provide some insight in this (powershell beginner)

Comment: What does `$ServerList` contain? And what type is it? (test with `$ServerList.getType()`)

Comment: You're not providing `Out-File` with any input - it won't magically know what you'd like in the file :)

Comment: @T.Me: $serverlist is a notepadfile with on each line a servername. Type= IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I also tried "$output | out-file -FilePath C:\temp\ServerStatus.txt" Same result however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `$serverList` might contain one or more empty lines, leading to the error you're seeing.

You can filter out empty and whitespace-only lines with `Where-Object` in the `foreach()` loop declaration:

```
$output = foreach ($s in $ServerList |Where-Object {$_.Trim() -ne ''}){
    # ...
}
```

The [`String.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim) method will remove any leading and trailing whitespace characters, so if `$_.Trim()` equals an empty string `''`, then we know the original must have been either an empty string already or all whitespace. The `-ne` operator means **n**ot **e**qual.

Comment: that solved the issue indeed. Weird thins is that i checked the list 9x to make sure there were no empty lines or whitespaces. Anyway, thank you for the help and explanation.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer solved the problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by cclicking the checkmark on the left :)